# Import csv, manipulate and export to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file, which contains some rows and columns. I need to pick some specific values out of that table, enhance them and then export them to another csv file.

My Python 3 code looks like this:

```
import csv
from urllib.parse import quote

afn='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=a1&aid=7909&oid=1031&url='
zx='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=z1&aid=3814&oid=1031&zanpid=##zxClickID##&userid=##UserID##&url='
zxpn='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=z1&aid=3840&oid=1031&zanpid=##zxClickID##&userid=##UserID##&url='
la='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?aid=3843&oid=1031&c1=leadalliance&c2=XXXXX&c3=default&clid=YYYYY&url='
tv='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?aid=7639&oid=1031&c1=leadalliance&c2=XXXXX&c3=default&clid=YYYYY&url='


with open('input_csv.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    matrixreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in matrixreader:
        va = afn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vzx = zx+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vzxpn = zxpn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vla = la+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vtv = tv+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
    liste = [[row['Name'], va, vzx, vzxpn, vla, vtv]]
    print(liste)

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        a = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        a.writerows(liste)
```

As an output I just receive the last row of `input.csv` exported to `output.csv`. It seems to me as if the code just overwrites the first row.

`input.csv` looks like this:

```
*Name,Promocode,Link

BASE Plus + iPhone 7,ASDFNOWEDF,base.de/base-plus

BASE Pro + iPhone 7,JBONEDGASD,base.de/base-pro

BASE Light + iPhone 7,NAFODSFNTE,base.de/base-light

BASE Pur + iPhone 7,NAEWRIONF,base.de/base-pur*
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help,
Cheers,
Franz

Comment: thank you guys. errikos your solution made it.

Answer (score 1):

The one problem is that you try to update your `liste` variable outside of the read loop. The other problem is that you re-assign to the `liste` variable, instead of [appending](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to it.

However, you don't need to collect all rows in a list and then write them to the output. You can do that by writing each row the moment you read and form it.

```py
with open('input_csv.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile_in:
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile_out:
        matrixreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile_in)
        a = csv.writer(csvfile_out, delimiter=',')
        for row in matrixreader:
            va = afn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
            vzx = zx+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
            vzxpn = zxpn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
            vla = la+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
            vtv = tv+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
            a.writerow([row['Name'], va, vzx, vzxpn, vla, vtv])
```

This is way more efficient and memory friendly, especially if the input file is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the **liste** assignment inside the if loop -

```
import csv
from urllib.parse import quote

afn='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=a1&aid=7909&oid=1031&url='
zx='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=z1&aid=3814&oid=1031&zanpid=##zxClickID##&userid=##UserID##&url='
zxpn='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?v=z1&aid=3840&oid=1031&zanpid=##zxClickID##&userid=##UserID##&url='
la='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?aid=3843&oid=1031&c1=leadalliance&c2=XXXXX&c3=default&clid=YYYYY&url='
tv='https://r.refinedads.com/bs-mapping.php?aid=7639&oid=1031&c1=leadalliance&c2=XXXXX&c3=default&clid=YYYYY&url='


with open('input_csv.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    matrixreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    liste=[] # initialize here
    for row in matrixreader:
        va = afn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vzx = zx+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vzxpn = zxpn+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vla = la+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        vtv = tv+quote(row['Link']+'&prf[pid]=[PARTNERID]&prf[a]=[AFFID]'+'-'+row['Promocode'])
        liste = liste.append([[row['Name'], va, vzx, vzxpn, vla, vtv]]) # keep appending
    print(liste)

    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        a = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        a.writerows(liste)
```